# C: Cannot read from 2 pipe file descriptors without losing the other one

Tags: c, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

I have C code that is simulating the bash command `ls | wc`. One of the things I want to achieve is to be able to to read the output of each command so I can print them - both `ls` and `wc` when `ls` is piped. This issue that I'm facing is whenever I read one of the commands is I somehow lose the other.

Observe the following code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LS_PATH "/bin/ls"
#define WC_PATH "/usr/bin/wc"

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    int link[2], link2[2];

    char *const arg1[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char *const arg2[] = {"wc", NULL};

    char *buffer1[4096], buffer2[4096];

    pipe(link);
    pipe(link2);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(link[0]);
        close(link[1]);
        execv(LS_PATH, arg1);
        perror("error1");
    }
    else
    {

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            dup2(link[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(link2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(link[1]);
            close(link[0]);
            close(link2[1]);
            close(link2[0]);
            execv(WC_PATH, arg2);
            perror("error2");
        }
        else
        {

            close(link[1]);

            close(link2[1]);

            // the following two lines of code is the point of interest
            read(link[0], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));   // ls
            read(link2[0], buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));  // wc

            printf("%s\n", buffer1);

            printf("%s\n", buffer2);
        }
    }
}
```

Focus mainly on the following code statements:

```c
read(link[0], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));   // ls
read(link2[0], buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));  // wc
```

`ls` is being read first into `buffer1`, it prints fine, but then `buffer2` which is reading `wc` just returns 0.

If I were to switch the ordering of the above code statements such that I would have the following:

```c
read(link2[0], buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));  // wc
read(link[0], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));   // ls
```

Then `wc` being read into `buffer2` works fine as if I ran the command `ls | wc` in the terminal, however, `ls` in `buffer1` would not print.

I can't get both, only one or the other.

How do I get both?

Comment: You have two readers on the same pipe trying to consume the same data. That won't work. Either have the `wc` process read from `link[0]` or have the parent read from `lnk[0]`, but having both try won't work.

Comment: I don't think I'm using the same pipe - at least from my understanding. I visualize it as `ls --> pipe1 --> wc --> pipe2`.

All I'm doing is reading from pipe1 and pipe2.

Would you suggest that I do it in different processes - not sure why that would affect things?

Comment: You are reading the same end of the same pipe in two different processes. The `wc` process reads from `link[0]` since that its standard input. The parent process reads from `link[0]` because that's one of the two lines of code that are your point of interest. Either `ls` can provide `wc`'s standard input or the parent process can read from its output, but if you do both, you won't know who will wind up getting what. (Is it clear to you why you can't get both?)

Comment: I sort of understand it now. With the commands `dup2(link[0], STDIN_FILENO);` and `dup2(link2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);`. I was making a pipe where the input was `ls` and the output was `wc`. Reading from `ls` however, would block the pipe and so `wc` would receive nothing and return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(link[0], STDIN_FILENO); // ** HERE **
        dup2(link2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(link[1]);
        close(link[0]);
        close(link2[1]);
        close(link2[0]);
        execv(WC_PATH, arg2);
        perror("error2");
    }
```

Notice that `wc` reads from `link[0]`.

```
        // the following two lines of code is the point of interest
        read(link[0], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));   // ls   ** HERE **
        read(link2[0], buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));  // wc
```

Notice that the parent process also tries to read from `link[0]`.

You can't get both because data written to a pipe can only be read from it once. If `wc` reads `ls`'s output to count its characters, then you can't also read `ls`'s output in the parent. If the parent reads `ls`'s output out of the pipe, then `wc` can't get it also because it's not in the pipe anymore. That's why you can only get one or the other -- if one thing reads the pipe, then it's not in the pipe for the other to read.

There are a lot of ways you can fix this, depending on your requirements.

1. You can use three pipes with the extra pipe being `wc`'s standard input. The parent process would have to copy data from pipe that has `ls`'s output to the pipe that is `wc`'s input.
2. You can add a third process, an instance of `tee` that duplicates the data.
3. You can have `ls` write to a temporary file. Both `wc` and your parent process can read that file. Files allow the same data to be read more than once, unlike pipes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up going with 3. I wrote the results of `ls` into a file. Then opened the file again but for reading only `fd = open("test.in", O_RDONLY);`. And then passes it as the input `dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);`.